# Tensorflowjs count black pixels from image

Tags: tensorflow.js

I am reading RGB images in tensorflow.js and need to find out the number of black pixels [0,0,0] in that image? Is there any method to do this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tensor image is a 3d tensor without the transparency

Given t a tensor image, the following will return the number of black pixels

```js
t = tf.tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0], [2, 2, 3])
t.sum(-1).equal(tf.zeros(t.shape.slice(0, -1))).sum().print() // 2
```

We sum each pixel value (sum over the axis -1) and create a 2d tensor with same width and height as initial tensor. Both tensors are compared and the last `tf.sum` will count where the first `tf.sum` tensor has 0 values.